# Hide a custom action button on click displaying a text in WooCommerce admin orders list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, orders

I am creating woocommerce plugin to send order details via WhatsApp. Here is my plugin code

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'dvs_whatsapp_msg_list_column' );
function dvs_whatsapp_msg_list_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['dvs_show_whatsapp'] = 'WhatsApp';
    return $columns;
}
 
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'dvs_whatsapp_msg_list_column_content' );
function dvs_whatsapp_msg_list_column_content( $column ) {
    global $post;
    if ( 'dvs_show_whatsapp' === $column ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
        $firstname = $order->get_billing_first_name();
        $lastname = $order->get_billing_last_name();
        $phone = $order->get_billing_phone();
        $ordernum = $order->get_order_number();
        $total = $order->get_total();
        $payment = $order->get_payment_method_title();
        $country = $order->get_billing_country();
        $calling_code = WC()->countries->get_country_calling_code($country);
        $whatsappnum = $calling_code.$phone;

        $msg = 'Hello ' .$firstname. ' ' .$lastname. ', your order #' .$ordernum. ' has been received. The order amount is ' .$total. '. Your payment method is ' .$payment.  '. Please contact us if you have any question regarding your order. Thank you.';
        
echo '<a href="https://wa.me/' .$whatsappnum. '?text=' .urlencode($msg).'" target="blank" class="dvs-whatsapp-btn">Send WhatsApp</a>';
    }
}
```

This is output
[image]

I want when shop manager or admin click the Send Whatsapp link then it will hide the link and show Message sent so shop manager or admin can know the details of this msg is already sent.

Please help.

Comment: I would suggest updating the order meta via AJAX when the link is clicked. Storing something along the lines of `whatsapp_link_sent: 1` in the order meta. Then base the output in your column on that value.

Comment: @Terminator-Barbapapa your point in valid sir, it should be like update_post_meta( $order->id, '_dvs_whatsapp_order_link', '1' ); and then in function i can use the condition but how to update_post_meta when link clicked ?

Comment: You can use jQuery to detect when the link is clicked and trigger an AJAX call that will update the order meta and change your link to 'Link sent' via the callback function. Check the WordPress documentation on [using AJAX in plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is not the way to achieve this. You will use the following instead to hide the link and display "Message sent" once an external link has been clicked:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'dvs_whatsapp_msg_list_column' );
function dvs_whatsapp_msg_list_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['whatsapp'] = __('WhatsApp', 'woocommerce');
    return $columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'dvs_whatsapp_msg_list_column_content' );
function dvs_whatsapp_msg_list_column_content( $column ) {
    if ( 'whatsapp' === $column ) {
        global $the_order;

        if( ! $the_order->get_meta('_wapp_sent') ) {
            echo '<a href="?post_type=shop_order&send=dvs_whatsapp&order_id=' . $the_order->get_id() .' target="blank" class="dvs-whatsapp button">' . __("Send WhatsApp") . '</a>';
        }
        else {
            echo __("Message sent", "woocommerce");
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'dvs_redirect_whatsapp_send' );
function dvs_redirect_whatsapp_send() {
    global $pagenow;

    # Check current admin page.
    if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'shop_order'
    && isset($_GET['send']) && $_GET['send'] == 'dvs_whatsapp' && isset($_GET['order_id']) && $_GET['order_id'] > 0 ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $_GET['order_id'] );

        $msg = sprintf( __("Hello %s %s, your order #%s has been received. The order amount is %s. Your payment method is %s. %s", "woocommerce"),
            $order->get_billing_first_name(),
            $order->get_billing_last_name(),
            $order->get_order_number(),
            $order->get_total(),
            $order->get_payment_method_title(),
            __("Please contact us if you have any question regarding your order. Thank you.", "woocommerce")
        );

        $whatsapp_num = WC()->countries->get_country_calling_code( $order->get_billing_country() ) . $order->get_billing_phone();

        update_post_meta( $_GET['order_id'], '_wapp_sent', 'true' ); // Mark order as WhatsApp message sent

        wp_redirect( 'https://wa.me/' . $whatsappnum . '?text=' . urlencode($msg) ); // Redirect to WhatsApp sending service
        exit;
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you, the code is perfect. But last thing can we open whatsapp link in new tab ? like targer="blank"

Comment: Thanks, I have added it. Your skills are great sir

if( ! $the_order->get_meta('_wapp_sent') ) {
            echo '<a href="?post_type=shop_order&send=dvs_whatsapp&order_id=' . $the_order->get_id() .'" class="dvs-whatsapp-btn" target="blank" style="width:100%;text-align:center;border: 1px solid #53c661;padding: 5px 10px;border-radius: 5px;background:#53c661;color: #fff;">' . __("Send WhatsApp") . '</a>';

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do the trick:

**jQuery to insert on your page**

```
jQuery('.dvs-whatsapp-btn').click(function(){
    jQuery('<span class="link-clicked">Link clicked!</span>').insertAfter('.dvs-whatsapp-btn');
    jQuery('.dvs-whatsapp-btn').hide();
});
```

Comment: no sir, it displays this: https://i.imgur.com/3MNdPxm.png and also when we refresh the page it again display send whatsapp link.

Comment: If you want the page ALWAYS to say that the link was clicked after it's been clicked (and not change on refresh) then you're looking at something entirely different from what I sent...  You'll need to add a lot of custom PHP, a new database column, and a function to handle the input from the page.  So in that case you're not looking at jQuery at all, rather at [something like this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages) (custom WordPress admin page input handler).  This is outside the scope of stackexchange, unfortunately.